# How to override k6 CLI arguments from within the script?

Tags: load-testing, k6

I have a rather complicated setup which forces me to pass  `--duration` and `--vus` to k6 CLI.

It ends up looking like

```
k6 run --vus 200 --duration 60s fixed-scenarios.js
```

Because of this my custom scenarios are being overridden by a default scenario.

Is there a way to prevent it from within the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In k6 [order of presence](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/k6-options/how-to/#order-of-precedence) cli flags will override everything else.

```js
import http from "k6/http";

const options = {
  foo_scenario: {
    executor: "shared-iterations",
    vus: 1,
    iterations: 1,
    maxDuration: "10s",
  },
};

export default function () {
  http.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

- If you only run with `k6 run script.js` it will make one request.
- If you override with cli flags, like `k6 run script.js --vus 10 --iterations 10`  it'll make 10 ten requests.

Comment: So, basically there is no way to override it from the script. Was hoping for an undocumented trick.